# IsDefault button click does not update last trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, button, focus

Textbox does not save it's values (UpdateSourceTrigger) when Button code is executed through IsDefault keyboard enter key

I use .focus in code-behind for a fix, is there a better fix?

Please don't suggest UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged because I don't want the textbox code to execute on every keystroke.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" DataContext="{Binding}">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="120">
<TextBox Text="{Binding ShowTextBox,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"  />
<Button Name="btnOK" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding cmdOK}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

code-behind

```
Class MainWindow
Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim vmMain1 As New vmMainWindow
    Me.DataContext = vmMain1

End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    ' btnOK.Focus()  'this line would be needed to get a fix that I am using now
End Sub
End Class
```

Viewmodel

```
Public Class vmMainWindow
Private _cmdOk As RelayCommand
Public ReadOnly Property cmdOK As RelayCommand
    Get
        If _cmdOk Is Nothing Then
            _cmdOk = New RelayCommand(Sub()
                                          MessageBox.Show(ShowTextBox)
                                      End Sub)
        End If
        Return _cmdOk
    End Get
End Property
Private _ShowTextBox As String = ""
Public Property ShowTextBox As String
    Get
        Return _ShowTextBox
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _ShowTextBox = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

If I uncomment the btnOK.Focus() I get a working result.
A problem with this fix is I don't know how `<Window.InputBindings><KeyBinding Key="A" Modifiers="Alt"/></Window.InputBindings>`
would use the fix because it doesn't have a code-behind feature.

Thank you for any input!
Josh

Comment: What do you mean with "...I don't want the textbox code to execute on every keystroke..." exactly? I don't see any event handler for TextChanged event in your code above. UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is actually what you should use in this scenario, it is meant for such use cases if you to avoid code-behind stuff.

Comment: every keystroke because UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged causes every keystroke inside the textbox to be processed by your viewmodel.